# In R programming, struggling with table() function on dataset

Tags: r, dataset, analysis

I'm doing **R** programming question on a dataset called birthwt. First of all in order to install and load the dataset. Type the following command

```
library(MASS)
birthwt
```

output is shown something like this:

[image: birthwt]

the dataset is about "Risk Factors Associated with Low Infant Birth Weight".

I'm using `table()` function (or some other method)  to find out how many women in the study were 1) white, 2) who smoked and 3) had babies who were considered to have low birth weight. (This means all three attributes/characteristics together.)

Here's my code:

```
birthwt3 <- data.frame(birthwt$race, birthwt$smoke,birthwt$low)
table(birthwt3)
```

Here's the output:

[image: table form]

But viewing the output, the multi-dimensional table becomes more difficult to follow and I could not find the answer for that question.

Can anyone help me with the question and what other useful functions I can use to view multi-dimensional table that is not difficult to follow?

Comment: I think you want to take a look at `xtabs()`, `xtabs(~ race + smoke + low, data = birthwt)`, then you can easily change argument in order to count groups/sum variables. Try for instance to change the order of variables in xtabs.

Comment: You can also take a look at `ftable(birthwt3)`. As you can see, there are options in `base R`.

Comment: please don't post screen capture, copy paste text output instead

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely make use of the `group_by` and `summarise` functions provided by the `dplyr` package. Try this:

```
birthwt <- MASS::birthwt
### install dplyr if you haven't already
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

birthwt %>% 
    group_by(race, smoke, low) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
```

You should get this:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   race, smoke [?]
    race smoke   low     n
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     0     0    40
 2     1     0     1     4
 3     1     1     0    33
 4     1     1     1    19
 5     2     0     0    11
 6     2     0     1     5
 7     2     1     0     4
 8     2     1     1     6
 9     3     0     0    35
10     3     0     1    20
11     3     1     0     7
12     3     1     1     5
```

Now it's easy to answer questions like "How many women of race X smoked and had babies below weight?"